# Programming touch on non-touch supported computer in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a touch screen laptop (Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 15, Windows 10) but on Unity, if I run the code:

```
    if (Input.touchSupported)
        print("supported");
    else
        print("not supported");
```

It prints that it is not supported. I am trying to make Pong, but you control both paddles and try to get a high score. Here is the code for trying to work past the fact that no touches are ever seen as touches. The code is supposed to move the paddle up or down.

```
      if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
        if (Input.mousePosition.x < Screen.width / 2)
        {
            //Begin Section: Touch left side
            if (mousePos.y > transform.position.y)
            {
                yPos = gameObject.transform.position.y + (paddleSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else
            {
                yPos = gameObject.transform.position.y - (paddleSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            //End of section
        }

    }
```

This works, the only problem is, the paddles have to move independently of each other. So I programmed the other paddle the same way. But, when I run the program and touch my screen with both fingers, the paddles freak out and don't work.

**Question: I need a way to program touch support for both paddles. *This can be answered in two ways*: Either telling me how to program around not having touch support, or how to get Unity to realize I do have touch support**

Any help with this would be hugely appreciated! Thanks!

Update: I forgot to add that I already tested the above code on my Android and it freaks out when you use two hands, otherwise it is flawless.

Comment: You can search for "fake touch" i wrote something like this while porting android game to standalone. Or just use mouse input, unity will simulate touch on touch-screen devices.

Comment: @PawełMarecki I did this and tested on my tablet. It goes out of control because of multiple touches

Comment: Yes, its possible. In my case i game was based only on single touch. I think it will be hard to simulate multitouch on "mouse" input. Sorry but cant help more. 
Edit: One more thing. Have you tested on W10 in Tablet Mode?

Comment: @Luke did you try just using touches (Input.touches) not having in mind what Input.touchSupported says? Could work, try it.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski Yes, to no effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also download Unity Remote 4 for your Mobile phone. 
It really helped me a lot : http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityRemote4.html

**edit**:

1. Download & install Unity Remote 4 on your device.
2. Enable USB debugging on your device and connect it to your pc.
3. Start Unity Remote 4 and then restart Unity.
4. In Unity, navigate to: Edit -> Project Settings -> Editor.
5. In the Inspector, you can select now under "Unity remote' your device.
6. Hit the Play Button in Unity.